# What does a dangerous query string look like?

Tags: c#, html, security, query-string

I want to see if my encoding is working however the example I made just reverts back to non encoded after it goes back to the page.

```
<a href="http://search.msn.com/results.aspx%3fq%3dIamBad">Click Here!</a>
```

Turns back into

```
<a href="http://search.msn.com/results.aspx?q=IamBad">Click Here!</a>
```

**Edit**

> UrlEncode Untrusted input is used in a
>   URL (such as a value in a
>   querystring)  Click
>   Here!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx

So my question is I am trying to see if something is not working right(ie why does it make the query string part look normal again).

Is it because the query string contains nothing really out of the ordinary. Or is something re encoding it back to its original form?

Comment: I don't understand this question? Why do you encode it? What means bad in your example?

Comment: According to MS a query string can have untrusted input in it that can be harmful and do XSS attack. See Edit

Comment: I'm sure everybody here is aware of that. What's your question? I'm still confused.

Comment: I am trying to verify if my code is actually encoding the query string. Everytime I look at it through firebug it looks like it is not. I am trying to figure out if it is the input of the query string that matters or if something else is going wrong and not encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply do not redisplay inputs from a user that come in via a form submission or through the query string, either redisplaying it to that user directly or storing it in a database that would then display it to other users of the site.

Say you have a hyperlink like this

```
/default.aspx?message=%3cscript%3ealert('Hello+world')%3b%3c%2fscript%3e
```

What you do *not* want to do is this

```
string message = Request.QueryString["message"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    directlyDisplayedLiteral.Text = message;
```

Because what would happen is that when that when the page loads, the user is going to see a message box pop up on screen. All this script produces is a stupid little message box, but it could be doing other malicious things to your users.

Instead, you want to encode the input before displaying it, so it becomes something harmless.

```
string message = Request.QueryString["message"];
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
    directlyDisplayedLiteral.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(message);
```

So all that happens is that `<script>alert('Hello world');</script>` is written to the screen, which is actually `&lt;script&gt;alert('Hello world');&lt;/script&gt;` in HTML. There's no message box, no script actually executing, it's just benign text on a screen.

Answer (score 0):

An example of a dangerous query string is below.

```
<a href="results.aspx?q=<script>alert('Attack')</script>">Click Here!</a>
```

What you really should be testing for isn't simply if the URL is encoded - but what happens when that attack is performed on your page.

Comment: Hi. I am not testing if the url is encoded. I am trying to encode the url myself on the server side through the MS XSS library. I am trying to verify if it actually did the encoding

Comment: The Anti-XSS library? Are you trying to use the httpmodule then to automatically encode your code? It only works on server controls.